# How should I use the decodeuricomponent?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, knex.js

```
router.get("/stocks/authed/:symbol", function (req, res, next) {
  req.db
    .from("stocks")
    .select("*")
    .modify(function(queryBuilder) {
      if (req.query.from && req.query.to) {
          queryBuilder.whereBetween('timestamp',[`%${req.query.from}%`,`%${req.query.to}%`]);
      }
  })
    .where("symbol", "=", req.params.symbol)
    .then((rows) => {
      res.json({ Error: false, Message: "Success", Cities: rows })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
      res.json({ Error: true, Message: "Error in MySQL query" })
    })
})
```

This is the code that I've got right now, and the url is 
http://localhost:3000/stocks/authed/AAL?from=2020-03-15T00%3A00%3A00.000Z&to=2020-03-20T00%3A00%3A00.000Z

To allow the wherebetween to read the url properly I think I need to decode the url using decodeuricomponent

How should I do it? I've tried surround the `%${req.query.from}%`,`%${req.query.to}%` but didn't worked...

Comment: Not sure about that date format, but I'm pretty sure the `queryBuilder` callback needs to `return` something

Comment: @ChrisG no need to return anything from those callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to learn really basics how things should be done with express and knex, so I thought that it is better to give here general tips how to debug your app and knex code.

You can start debugging by printing out those `req.query.from` and `req.query.to` variables and see if express is automatically applying decoding URL parameter to plain javascript string.

Then you should pretty much never need `%` wildcard marks in your `knex` queries unless you are using `like` operator, where `%ABC%` will match also for example with `somthingABC`, `ABCsadpokq` and `anything goes ABC yup % is a wildcard`.

Good way to learn writing queries with `knex` is to first figure out / test what kind of SQL you are trying to generate and then use query builder's

```
.toSQL()
```

Method to printout what kind of query your `knex` code is generating.